# pgrep prints a different pid than expected

Tags: bash, grep, command-substitution

I wrote a small script and for some reason I need to escape any spaces passed in parameters to get it to work.

I read numerous other articles about people with this issue and it is typically due to not quoting $@, but all of my variables are quoted within the script and the parameters quoted on the command line as well.  Also, if I run the script in debug mode the line that is returned can be run successfully via copy paste but fails when executed from within the script.

CODE:

```
connections ()
{
    args="$@"
    pid="$(pgrep -nf "$args")"
    echo $pid
    # code that shows TCP and UDP connections for $pid
}
connections "$@"
```

EXAMPLE:

`bash test.sh "blah blah"`

fails and instead returns the pid of the currently running shell

`bash test.sh "blah\ blah"`

succeeds and returns the pid of the process you are searching for via pgrep

Comment: This isn't your problem, exactly, but I don't quite understand your use of `"$@"` here. `connections` seems clearly designed to take only a single argument, and it will misbehave if it receives multiple arguments (in that it will pass all of those arguments separately to `pgrep -nf`, such that the first argument is matched against the command line and all subsequent arguments are matched only against the process name). So why not just use `"$1"` instead? Or, better yet, give some sort of error or warning if there are multiple arguments?

Comment: I already attempted that and had the same issue.  If i replace all instances of $@ with $1 the same issue is experienced(escaping the space works, while not escaping the space pulls the pid of the current shell )

Comment: Yes: as I said, your misuse of `"$@"` is not the problem. But I still don't see *why* you want to misuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with `"$@"`.

If you add a `-l` option to `pgrep`, you can see *why* it's matching the current process.

The script you're running *also includes what you're trying to search for in its own arguments*.

It's like doing this, and seeing `grep`:

```
$ ps -U $USER -o pid,cmd | grep gnome-terminal
12410 grep gnome-terminal
26622 gnome-terminal --geometry=180x65+135+0
```

The reason the backslash makes a difference?  `pgrep` thinks backslash+space just means space.  It doesn't find your script, because that contains `blah\ blah`, not `blah blah`.